# Can't target two different dropdowns properly by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have two seperate dropdowns, whose hover states can't be target by css based on the html markup. I tried to solve this by jQuery and I am halfway done. One problem still exists all the time and I am trying to solve this by days now.

If I hover the **link** of the **second** dropdown and moves the mouse really fast to the **link** of the **first** dropdown and then move the mouse immediately into the **container** of the displayed **first** dropdown, this dropdown menu disappears. It seems that my script removes the adding css classes in this case. This situation only appears with fast mouse movement but it drives me crazy. I am unable to figure out why this happens. I include a jsfiddle demo, where you can see the problem by yourself.

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $body = $('body'),
        $tg_header = $('#main-header'),
        $tg_top_menu = $('ul.nav'),
        /*$tg_submenu_link = $('.tg-submenu__link'),*/
        $tg_submenu_link_tg = $('.tg-submenu__link--tg'),
        $tg_submenu_link_abteilungen = $('.tg-submenu__link--abteilungen'),
        $tg_submenu = $('.tg-submenu'),
        $tg_submenu_tg = $('.tg-submenu__tg'),
        $tg_submenu_abteilungen = $('.tg-submenu__abteilungen'),
        et_menu_hover_triggered = false;

                /* General Hiding Function for first mega menu */
        function tg_hide_tg() {
            setTimeout( function () {
                if ($tg_top_menu.find('.tg-submenu__link--tg:hover').length == 0 && $('.tg-submenu__tg:hover').length == 0) {
                    $body.removeClass('tg-submenu__tg--active')
                };
                }, 50);
        }

                /* General Hiding Function for second mega menu */
        function tg_hide_abteilungen() {
            setTimeout( function () {
                if ($tg_top_menu.find('.tg-submenu__link--abteilungen:hover').length == 0 && $('.tg-submenu__abteilungen:hover').length == 0) {
                    $body.removeClass('tg-submenu__abteilungen--active')
                };
                }, 50);
        }

                /* Mouse Hover Mega Link 1 and Leave Link */
        $tg_submenu_link_tg.mouseenter(function() {
            $body.addClass('tg-submenu__tg--active');
        }).mouseleave(function() {
            tg_hide_tg();
        });

                /* Mouse Leave Mega Menu Container 1 */
        $tg_submenu_tg.mouseleave(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                if ($('.tg-submenu__link--tg:hover').length == 0 && $('.tg-submenu__tg:hover').length == 0 ) {
                    $body.removeClass('tg-submenu__tg--active');
                };
            },50)
        });

                /* Mouse Hover Mega Link 2 and Leave Link */
        $tg_submenu_link_abteilungen.mouseenter(function() {
            $body.addClass('tg-submenu__abteilungen--active');
        }).mouseleave(function() {
            tg_hide_abteilungen();
        })

        /* Mouse Leave Mega Menu Container 2 */
        $tg_submenu_abteilungen.mouseleave(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                if ($('.tg-submenu__link--abteilungen:hover').length == 0 && $('.tg-submenu__abteilungen:hover').length == 0 ) {
                    $body.removeClass('tg-submenu__abteilungen--active');
                };
            },50)
        });
    });
```

HTML-Markup

```
<body>
<header id="main-header">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="et-top-navigation">
          <div class="tg-mainMenu__left">
              <nav id="top-menu-nav">
                  <ul id="top-menu" class="nav">
            <li id="menu-item-154" class="tg-submenu__link tg-submenu__link--tg menu-item"><a href="#">MEGA LINK 1</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-156" class="tg-submenu__link tg-submenu__link--abteilungen menu-item"><a href="#">MEGA LINK 2</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-166" class="menu-item menu-item"><a href="#">Normal Link 3</a></li>
          </ul>                     
         </nav>
            </div><!-- TG-mainMenu__left-->
            <div class="tg-mainMenu__right">
              <nav id="top-menu-nav">
                    <ul id="top-menu" class="nav">
            <li id="menu-item-154" class="menu-item menu-item"><a href="#">Normal Link 4</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-154" class="menu-item menu-item"><a href="#">Normal Link 5</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-154" class="menu-item menu-item"><a href="#">Normal Link 6</a></li>
          </ul>                     
        </nav>
            </div> <!-- tg-mainMenu__right -->
        </div> <!-- #et-top-navigation -->
    <!-- TG Mega 1 -->
    <div class="tg-submenu tg-submenu__tg">
      <div class="container tg-submenu__content">
        <h1>
         MEGA MENU 1
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Abteilungen Mega -->
    <div class="tg-submenu tg-submenu__abteilungen">
        <div class="container tg-submenu__content">
          <h1>
            MEGA MENU 2
          </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- .container -->
</header>
</body>
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hfammzce/

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why this is happening. But you can use jQuery .show() and .hide() instead of using add/remove class and opacity.

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1dzyszdq/

```
    /* General Hiding Function for first mega menu */
    function tg_hide_tg() {
        setTimeout( function () {
            if ($tg_top_menu.find('.tg-submenu__link--tg:hover').length == 0 && $('.tg-submenu__tg:hover').length == 0) {
                $(".tg-submenu__tg").hide();
            };
            }, 50);
    }


    /* Mouse Hover Mega Link 1 and Leave Link */
    $tg_submenu_link_tg.mouseenter(function() {
        $('.tg-submenu__tg').show();
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        tg_hide_tg();
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the advice Evans! I'd prefer the css class solution, because beside these classes, I also add a class to the body container for a cover blend. I just removed it in the demo for overview aspect. Maybe refactoring the code could solve this problem. I will try this later and keep this thread up to date, if I found a solution if nobody has a solution for this